# How can I really work with Git and branches?

Tags: git, branch

I'm freelance developer and recently picked up the project that is hosted by Git. I decided to use a branch to work on my part. However I need some guidance as I never worked with Git before.

I did:

```
git clone <url_to_project>
```

and it gave me the source code in the directory ~/proj.

Now I need to pull the changes that was made and create a branch. The question is how do I do that?

Comment: Consider reading tutorials.  Git is ... different and you may end up in a corner.

Answer (score 3):

To pull the changes from the remote `master` branch and merge it into your local `master`:

```
git pull origin master
```

To create a new branch `new_feature`:

```
git checkout -b new_feature
```

You change branches by checking it out without the `-b` flag, e.g.:

```
git checkout master
git checkout new_feature
```

A good tutorial (and in fact an online book) is: [Pro Git](http://git-scm.com/book)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you actually learn to use the software.

There are a lot of great free resources out there... For example,

- *[Pro Git](http://git-scm.com/book/)* book
- http://gitref.org/

Comment: The second link is (effectively) broken as it redirects to a generic place.